# Readings on more general/abstract notions of induction related to logic

Tags: reference-request, induction, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

> Can someone suggest references to understand the more general/abstract
>   concept of induction?

Specifically, I am trying to justify to myself what is called induction on the "complexity of a formula" found in introductory logic texts. I'm reading *Chiswell and Hodges* and *CH Leary*.

It seems to me that proving something using induction on complexity of a formula will only work if we know for sure that all formulas are built from propositional symbols from the bottom. But it is not clear to me that the definition of a formula necessitates this. But I thought if formulas are restricted to be finite strings from a language $LP(\sigma)$ then since each formula can be represented on a tree (a modified concept borrowed from Graph Theory in the first of two books I mentioned) then each must be of finite "height" and must have a propositional symbol as a leaf.

But either way I am not all that comfortable with it and would like to read more. I read the section on Induction and Recursion in the book on logic by *Enderton* which seems to explain it but it looks like I would have to read that book **too** from the beginning because there are references to earlier sections. Either way wondering if there is a more comprehensive exposition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are asking for references, but you don't like the reference that you have (Enderton) because you'd have to read it?

Comment: @Carl Mummert: I'm asking for references on the subject. Enderton has a passing comment on the subject. I don't know where to look to be honest. Set  Theory books? If I started reading Enderton cover to cover that would be my 4th book on the subject (I would have *read* and not skimmed). Plus I'm guessing that's not the best place to look. Guess my wording is misleading though. Corrected.

Comment: Section 1.4 of Enderton's book is devoted to exploring this topic in detail.

Comment: You can see also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879874/well-formed-expression-polish-notation) for some comments regarding Enderton's exposition

Comment: A step-by-step discussion (with comments) is in sect. **1.2 INDUCTION ON THE COMPLEXITY OF WFF** of George Tourlakis, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Logic-George-Tourlakis/dp/0470280743/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1408297799&sr=8-1&keywords=George+Tourlakis+Mathematical+Logic) (2008), page 17-on.

Comment: See also the [Wikipedia article in *structural induction*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **[1]** could be of use. However, see **[2]** if you want a very abstract approach (an approach that is related to topics in the links I gave in my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853836/monotonicity-question-in-endertons-text-on-set-theory)).

**[1]** [**Handbook of Mathematical Induction**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420093649) by David S. Gunderson (over 900 pages)

**[2]** [**Elementary Induction on Abstract Structures**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486466787) by Yiannis N. Moschovakis